# Time Complexity for random call

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity

What will be the time complexity for the given code

```
int func(int n){
     int i;
     if(n<=0)
       return 0;
     else
     {
         i=random(n-1);
         return func(i)+func(n-1-i);
     }
       
 }
```

I think O(n) but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove that your time complexity is O(n), you need to prove that

```
return func(i)+func(n-1-i);
```

won't be called more than n times.
As long as n is decreasing by at least 1 (i being an int, from 0 to n, and n decreasing by i+1 every time) at each call, then you'll use this line maximum n times.

And, because without the recursive call, your time complexity is O(1), then, with recursive call, your time complexity is O(n), and you won't be able to calculate a better one as long as random could give 0 every time.

Comment: Note - the proof itself is trivial with complete induction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction